# Download File Progress Dialog

Tags: android, sdk

I want to perform a file download and show a dialog. But when I try to show the dialog I get a error, any help?

The problem is at `showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);`

Here is the error message : The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated

Heres my code:

```
public class download extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload();
        }
    });
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "http://practicalbuddhist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Synapses-Image-for-March-17-2010-Blog-Entry.jpg";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Running Download Test...");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask {

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Downloadtest.jpg");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;

}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the error message: The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated

This is a warning, not an error. You can either upgrade to using Fragments or ignore it.

Comment: how do i use fragments, i am new to this programming in java.

Comment: To help you open the Dialog, post your `onCreateDialog()` method and any LogCat errors in your question. On the other hand, switching to Fragments is _not_ simple, if you want to upgrade [start here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Hi, i just updated my code take a look at it and tell me what you think?

Comment: This should work fine, did you remember to add the permissions for `INTERNET` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`? It looks like an error occurs while you are downloading, add `e.printStackTrace();` into your empty catch block and watch your LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ProgressDialog and show() method that is not depracated instead of using showDialog. Declare your dialog in AsyncTask:

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
}
```

and in onPostExecute() use

```
pDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: is there a reason why i get this error though, i am in the learning process of java. so i want to learn how to use dialog for download and how to fix it.

Comment: ok, but why is it warning me. i have looked over various tutorials that show the same thing. And people claim to say its working. is there a fix for this warning because it doesnt work

Comment: It's warning because it's deprecated and Deprecated means "You can still use this, but don't count on it, because we will probably replace it with something else (or remove it entirely) in future software releases." The fix for this is in my answer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation

Comment: What do you mean that doesn't work in onPostExecute? Do you have an error or just it doesn't disappear?

Comment: You have to declare it as a field in your DownloadFileAsync class: private ProgressDialog pDialog;

Comment: I put the same  coding in how you displayed it above.

Comment: here is the logcat readings from when i click the button: 10-31 16:51:20.661: I/PowerManagerService-JNI(211): [Stability] PowerManagerService_userActivity JNI pass power key event to PowerManagerService userActivity()